# MySQL table self-join returns too many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I have a table, `my_table` with a primary key, `id` (`INT`), and further columns `foo` (`VARCHAR`) and `bar` (`DOUBLE`). Each `foo` should appear once in my table, with an associated `bar` value, but I know that I have several rows with identical `foo`s associated different `bar`s. How do I get a list of those rows containing the same `foo` value, but which have different `bar`s (say, different by more than 10.)?
I tried:

```
    SELECT t1.id, t1.bar, t2.id, t2.bar, t1.foo
    FROM my_table t1, my_table t2
    WHERE t1.foo=t2.foo
    AND t1.bar - t2.bar > 10.;
```

But I get lots and lots of results (more than the total number of rows in `my_table`). I feel I must be doing something very obviously stupid, but can't see my mistake.

Ah - thanks SWeko: I think I understand why I'm getting so many results, then. Is there a way in SQL of counting, for each `foo`, the number of rows with that `foo` but `bar`s differing by more than 10.?

Comment: different by 10 is t1.bar - t2.bar = 10

Comment: I think he meant different by at least 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for example, you have 5 rows with `foo='A'` and 10 rows with `foo='B'` the self-join will join each A-row with each other A-row (including itself) and each B-row with each other B-row, so a simple

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.bar, t2.id, t2.bar, t1.foo
FROM my_table t1, my_table t2
WHERE t1.foo=t2.foo
```

will return `5*5+10*10=125` rows. Filtering the values will cut that number down, but you might still have (significantly) more rows than you started with. E.g. if we presume that the B-rows have values of `bar` of 5 through 50 respectively, that would mean that they will be matched with:

```
bar = 5  - 0 rows that have bar less than -5
bar = 10 - 0 rows that have bar less than 0
bar = 15 - 0 rows that have bar less than 5
bar = 20 - 1 rows that have bar less than 10
bar = 25 - 2 rows that have bar less than 15
bar = 30 - 3 rows that have bar less than 20
bar = 35 - 4 rows that have bar less than 25
bar = 40 - 5 rows that have bar less than 30
bar = 45 - 6 rows that have bar less than 35
bar = 50 - 7 rows that have bar less than 40
```

so you will have 28 results for the B-rows alone, and that number rises with the square of the rows that have the same value of `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your latest question:

> Is there a way in SQL of counting, for each foo, the number of rows
>   with that foo but bars differing by more than 10.?

A query like this should work:

```
select t1.id, t1.foo, t1.bar, count(t2.id) as dupes
from my_table t1
  left outer join my_table t2 on t1.foo=t2.foo and (t1.bar - t2.bar) > 10
group by t1.id, t1.foo, t1.bar;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the same thing with the "new" `JOIN` syntax?

```
    SELECT t1.*,
           t2.*
      FROM my_table t1
      JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.foo = t2.foo
     WHERE (t1.bar - t2.bar) > 10
```

I don't suspect that that will fix your problem, but for me that's at least where I would start.

I might also try this:

```
    SELECT t1.*,
           t2.*
      FROM my_table t1
      JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.foo = t2.foo AND t1.id != t2.id
     WHERE (t1.bar - t2.bar) > 10
```

Comment: This is preferred, but it clearly isn't the problem, because it is exactly equivalent to the OP's query.

Comment: -1 The added query makes no sense. A row will never join to itself anyway, because you are already requiring that the matching rows have a different value for bar.  It is no good just "trying" random stuff and hoping the problem goes away.  You have to actually figure it out and fix it!

Comment: Why do you hate me, dan1111?